# python: equivalent to Javascript "||" to override non-truthful value

Tags: python

In Javascript I can do this:

```
function A(x) { return x || 3; }
```

This returns 3 if x is a "non-truthful" value like 0, null, false, and it returns x otherwise. This is useful for empty arguments, e.g. I can do `A()` and it will evaluate as 3.

Does Python have an equivalent? I guess I could make one out of the ternary operator [`a if b else c`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/python-ternary-operator) but was wondering what people use for this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `or` to do the same thing but you have to be careful because some unexpected things can be considered `False` in that arrangement.  Just make sure you want this behavior if you choose to do it that way:

```
>>> "" or 1
1
>>> " " or 1
' '
>>> 0 or 1
1
>>> 10 or 1
10
>>> ['a', 'b', 'c'] or 1
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> [] or 1
1
>>> None or 1
1
```

Answer (score 5):

The answer is `or`:

```
def A(x):
    return x or 3
```